What if i say wallahi on a useless thing and then break it?
me my brother and my dad went shopping , i wanted a bag of chips , and im in turkey currently and my brother said say wallohi you will let me play on your computer for one bag of chips i said wallahi , now i have to let him play

This is not recommended according to this verse:

وَ لَا تَجْعَلُوا اللَّهَ عُرْضَةً لِأَيْمَانِكُمْ أَنْ تَبَرُّوا وَ
تَتَّقُوا وَ تُصْلِحُوا بَيْنَ النَّاسِ وَ اللَّهُ سَمِيعٌ عَلِيمٌ
Do not make God a hindrance, through your oaths, to being pious and
godfearing, and putting things right between men Surely God is
All hearing, All knowing (224)

